# 502 Bad Gateway on Kibana DevTools every "now and then"

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

We have setup a Kubernetes cluster with Nginx. Within the cluster, we are running Elasticsearch and Kibana. Sometimes, when experimenting on Kibana DevTools console, we get a `502 bad gateway`. The weird aspect is that it only happens through the console, and only 1 time every 4-5 queries. So most of the times it works. This is the error:
[image: This is the error we get on the DevTool console]

This is the nginx yaml configuration:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
spec:
  rules:
...
```

Nginx controller was installed by following [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Tasks/contengsettingupingresscontroller.htm) as we are using Oracle Cloud.

Most of the Q&A I have found around are related to server configurations issues. While here most of the times work, so it should not be a configuration issue.

I did not get any luck by reading up on https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/. Worth to mention that I am using CloudFlare, but once again, in their documentation they say to check nginx configuration, as it is not on their end. https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003011431-Troubleshooting-Cloudflare-5XX-errors#502504error

Any insight is strongly appreciated.